# What is most recommended solutions to avoid dos attack for financial websites?

Tags: security, web-applications

I need to know to most recommended optimal solutions in world wide for avoid dos attack for financial websites.

Your comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple DDoS attack technique and you will probably not use the same protection against each of them.

Here you can find multiple DDoS attack technique/example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Attack_techniques

1. Reduce the attack's surface, you will next focus your protection on what you expose with your website.
2. Identify your limits, define :

- What is the normal and abnormal traffic on your website
- What is the maximum bandwidth of your network
- What is the maximum load that your server can tolerate
  Then you will be able to know if you are under an attack before being unavailable. That will also help you to customize your security products.

3. To mitigate the attack you can use a

- CDN or make sure you have a large bandwidth with multiple access point to your website
- Load balancer to balance the traffic between your web servers avoid overloading
- Increase (automatically or not) the the number of your servers according to the load they are facing
- Commercial product that will help you to mitigate the attack like firewall, IPS, WAF, Anti-DDoS on cloud-based platform or not.
- Limite the number of connection per IP (see the documentations below for examples)

Top 10 DDoS Attack :
https://www.imperva.com/docs/DS_Incapsula_The_Top_10_DDoS_Attack_Trends_ebook.pdf

Technical configuration :
https://us-cert.cisa.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DDoS%20Quick%20Guide.pdf

https://www.netscout.com/what-is-ddos/application-layer-attacks